# Query condition missed key schema element : Validation Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query `dynamodb` using the following code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  service: new AWS.DynamoDB(
    {
      apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
      region: "us-east-1"
    }),
  convertEmptyValues: true
});

dynamo.query({
  TableName: "Jobs",
  KeyConditionExpression: 'sstatus = :st',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':st': 'processing'
  }
}, (err, resp) => {
  console.log(err, resp);
});
```

When I run this, I get an error saying:

```
ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: id
```

I do not understand this. I have defined `id` as the partition key for the `jobs` table and need to find all the jobs that are in `processing` status.

Comment: Have you tried using id as partition key and status as sorting key?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You're trying to run a query using a condition that does not include the primary key. This is [how queries work in DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html). You would need to do a [scan for the info in your case](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html), however, I don't think that is the best option.

I think you want to set up a [global secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) and use that to query for the `processing` status.

Comment: Could you please discuss this here at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160644/migrated-from-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-47681108-query-condition-missed

Comment: Isn't a query vs a key lookup by definition already targeting a GSI? I'm reaching this error while running a query operation on a GSI...

Comment: @anon58192932 Without knowing specifics, my gut tells me the field you're trying to filter on is not in your GSI. If you've got specifics, even better.

Comment: There are a couple ways to reach this error. Two that I found were: 1) using the deprecated api in lieu of KeyConditionExpression and 2) a typo in my GSI definition. there was a mismatch between the value I wanted the GSI to be an index on and what the index actually was on. Deleting and re-defining the index fixed it.

Answer (score 27):

In another answer *@smcstewart* responded to this question. But he provides a link instead of commenting why this error occurs. I want to add a brief comment hoping it will save your time.

[AWS docs on Querying a Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html) states that you can do `WHERE` condition queries (e.g. `SQL query SELECT * FROM Music WHERE Artist='No One You Know'`) in the DynamoDB way, but with one important caveat:

> You MUST specify an EQUALITY condition for the PARTITION key, and you can optionally provide another condition for the SORT key.

Meaning **you can only use key attributes with `Query`**. Doing it in any other way would mean that DynamoDB would run a **full scan** for you which is **NOT efficient** - less efficient than using Global secondary indexes.

So if you need to query on non-key attributes using Query is usually NOT an option - best option is using [Global Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) as suggested by *@smcstewart*.

I found [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-gsi-dynamodb/) to be useful to create a Global secondary index manually.

If you need to add it using CloudFormation [here is a relevant page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-gsi.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error for a different scenario. Here is my scenario.
(It's very unlikely that anyone else ends up with this case, but incase)

I had a query working on a Table (say table A). Table A had a partition key m_id and sort key u_id.
I had a query to fetch data using m_id. The query was working.

'''

```
var queryParams = {
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':m_id': mId
         },
       KeyConditionExpression: 'm_id = :m_id',
       TableName: "A"
      };
    
   let connections = await docClient.query(queryParams).promise();
```

'''

I created another Table say Table B. I made some errors in naming keys so I simply deleted and created a table with the same name again, Table B. Table B had partition key m_id, and sort key s_id.

I copied pasted the same query which I was using for Table A, I changed Table name only because partition key had the same name.

To my shock, I get this expectation.

**"ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element"**

I rechecked all the names, I compared the query with the working query. Everything was fine.
I thought maybe because, I was deleting recreating Table B, it could be something with that. So I create a fresh Table with a new Name Table B2 with the same key names as Table B.

In my query that was throwing exceptions, I changed only the Table name from B to B2.
And the Exception was gone.

If you are getting this on a fresh table, where no query has worked earlier, creating a new Table with a **new name** is an option.

**If you delete a Table only to change partition key names, it may be safer to use a new name for Table as well** (Dynamo could be referring metadata by table names and not by internal identifiers, it is possible that old metadata stays even if you delete a table. Just a guess given I faced this case).

---

**EDIT:2022-July-12**

This error does not leave me. My own answer was helpful but one more case, **there was a trailing space in name of Key in the table**. And Dynamo does not even check for spaces in key names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an global secondary index for the status field.
Then, you code could look like smth like this:

```
dynamo.query({
  TableName: "Jobs",
  IndexName: 'status',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#s = :st',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':st': 'processing'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#s': 'status',
    },
}, (err, resp) => {
  console.log(err, resp);
});
```

Note: scan operation is indeed very costly, especially if you table is huge in size

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem using AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() with scan, for sample (nodejs):

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
        TableName: "product",
        FilterExpression: "#cg = :data",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#cg": "categoria",
        },

        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
             ":data": category,
        }
    };

docClient.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // for the log in server
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            res.json(err);
        } else {

            console.log("Scan succeeded.");
            res.json(data);

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not an advisable solution. Scan operation is very expensive!

Comment: yep rebuild your table, add some index and do query instead