# GraphQL AWS AMplify @connection not bringing in connected data

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I would like to have in the League tables all of the seasons and divisions as you can see with `data > seasons`. I have set it up as I believe would work using @connection.

So the question is, how would I have to change my division schema so that divisions are included in the `League`.

I have spent a good time reading over [@connections](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#has-one) & [@key](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#key) and understand that when using the key a hash is created with the `ID` that I have given them. But I do not understand enough having read the connections documentation multiple times as to why this wouldn't work.

I would love to understand this better, so i am giving all I can to try to develop an understanding!

n.b I believe it is worth mentioning also, that each time I change my schema and the `amplify mock` rebuilds the hash keys, they get added. I wonder if this has some impact? Should I be cleaning the SQLite completely with each schema change when keys are involved?
[image]

## League Schema

```
type League @model
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  logo: String
  seasons: [Season] @connection(keyName: "bySeason", fields: ["id"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivision", fields: ["id"])
}
```

## Seasons Schama

```
type Season @model @key(name: "bySeason", fields: ["leagueID"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  yearStart: AWSDate
  yearEnd: AWSDate
  leagueID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivision", fields: ["id"])
}
```

## Division Schema

```
type Division @model
@key(name: "byDivisionFromSeason", fields: ["leagueID" "name"])
@key(name: "byDivision", fields: ["seasonID", "leagueID"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  divisionSeasonFaId: String
  leagueID: ID!
  seasonID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  season: Season! @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
  teams: [TeamConnection] @connection(keyName: "byTeamDivision", fields: ["id"])
  games: [Game] @connection(keyName: "byGameForDivision", fields: ["id"])
  ageInput: String!
  level: Int!
}
```

## Queries

```
  listLeagues {
    items {
      name
      division {
        items {
          name
        }
      }
      seasons {
        items {
          name
          division {
            items {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

## Data

I have shown here that the structure is correct as the `Seasons` included in the `League` have the `Divisions` as expected

```
{
  "data": {
    "listLeagues": {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Southern Amateur League",
          "division": {
            "items": []
          },
          "seasons": {
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "2020-21",
                "division": {
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "name": "Junior Section Division 5B South"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Junior Section Division 4 South"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Intermediate Division 3"
                    },
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "2019-20",
                "division": {
                  "items": []
                }
              },
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Edit

Since reducing just the keys on division to `seasonID` and `leagueID` on each key, when clearing the data it appears to throw an unusual error. I had believed that return null on a @connection was perfectly valid?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this should be more a comment than an actual answer, but I need to describe the schema, I will delete it later if you consider it appropriate.

Jamie, just for testing, can you please try the following schema? It is basically the same schema proposed by Nader, just removing the field `name` from the `key`s on `Division`:

```
type League @model
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  logo: String
  seasons: [Season] @connection(keyName: "bySeason", fields: ["id"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivision", fields: ["id"])
}

type Season @model @key(name: "bySeason", fields: ["leagueID"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  yearStart: AWSDate
  yearEnd: AWSDate
  leagueID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivisionFromSeason", fields: ["id"])
}

type Division @model
@key(name: "byDivisionFromSeason", fields: ["seasonID", "leagueID"])
@key(name: "byDivision", fields: ["leagueID", "seasonID"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  divisionSeasonFaId: String
  leagueID: ID!
  seasonID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  season: Season! @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
  teams: [TeamConnection] @connection(keyName: "byTeamDivision", fields: ["id"])
  games: [Game] @connection(keyName: "byGameForDivision", fields: ["id"])
  ageInput: String!
  level: Int!
}
```

I think the error you obtained, i.e.:

```
"errors": [ { "message": "Query condition missed key schema element", "errorType": "DynamoDB:ValidationException", "data": null, "errorInfo": null, "path": [ "listLeagues", "items", 1, "division" ], "locations": [ { "line": 10, "column": 9, "sourceName": "GraphQL request" } ] }
```

can be motivated by running a query using the condition `name`.

Comment: Thanks @jccampanero. So, here is what I am wondering, with these schema changes, should I re add all the data? Or can it traverse through the data and update all the keys? As this doesn't make a difference sadly `          "division": {
            "items": []
          },`

Comment: I did a quick test, removed the data and readded, it did not change it.
Maybe I need to remove the local mocked sqlite db file and start again completely?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the mock data by deleting the entire mock data folder and re-running `amplify mock`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes Jamie, I must recognize that I have worked more directly with DynamoDB and not with Amplify, especially with the mock mechanism, but I think it will provide a fresh environment to test.

Comment: Ah, so indeed the key to me debugging was to remove the DB. I had been doing this in the past, however not religiously. So of course, when I got the schema right, I must not have flushed the DB. So this does return the divs now, with the league. However now I need to prove to myself I understand the concept.

Comment: So, in this particular case: the fields on the key `"leagueID", "seasonID"` mean. `leagueID` is a has key from `Division` Model that links the `Division > League` models.
The secondary key provided is then linked in the same way. `Season > League`. Both these keys act in the same way. Lookups between the two tables. What I do not understand, really is why having `"seasonID", "leagueID"` on both keys is not valid. Surely as it would be a reference `league > season` & `league > division` would mean its completely valid to have this?

Comment: I think, my main confusion/frustration is I cannot understand the "why" or "how". I could get things to work, but clearly as this "bug" has happened it shows I do not fully understand keys in `dynomodb`

Comment: Hi Jamie. I am happy to see that you could obtain the information finally. Regarding your question, the key point to understand is that DynamoDB is great, but you always have to clearly define your data access patterns. When you create your ```@key```s under the hood different indexes, primary or secondaries, are created in your tables. As you say, the first field will be always the primary or HASH key. Any additional fields constitute the SORT key, and allows you to refine your queries by filter by them. When you define the ```@connection```, you are creating a join by the provided HASH key.

Comment: In fact, I think you probably can get rid of the ```SORT``` fields in both keys on ```Division``` and your query must still work, I think that only the first one, the ```HASH``` key, is required to successfully resolve the @connection and fetch the data. Just remember, think about how you will query the data, and create your table indexes (your ```@key```s) according to that data access patterns. You always need to query, by equality, by the ```HASH``` key, and then you can define one or several ```SORT``` fields to additionally filter, this time with a broader set of operators, the results.

Comment: If you allow me, I will recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681108/query-condition-missed-key-schema-element-validation-error/47681908#47681908) stackoverflow question. Please do not forget to read the accepted answer [companion chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160644/migrated-from-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-47681108-query-condition-missed), it is one of the best explanations I have ever read about how Dynamo works. If you think that I could be of any help, please, just contact me.

Comment: Jaime, does it make more sense to you now?

Comment: I have been trying to locate examples that can help you understand what is happening when defining keys and relationships. I found this article: https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/. In it the author explains very well different ways of creating relationships and I think it can help you understand what happens when you create a key in one way or another, for me in fact it has been.

Comment: Brilliant thank you jccampanero!!! I will read these this evening :) Thank you again

Comment: Thank you very much, you're welcome Jaime. I hope the information will be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223725/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-jccampanero).

Comment: Sorry Jamie, I just saw your message. Sure, please tell me when you can chat and I'll try to connect and try to help you if I can.

Comment: I realized that you edited your question. Sorry, perhaps I gave you a wrong advice when I told you to get rid of the sort fields in the ```Division``` keys. I think it makes perfect sense from a DynamoDB point of view, but perhaps they are required by Amplify. We can review it later in the chat.

Comment: Jaime, I continued looking for information that can serve you to understand how DynamoDB actually works. I am sorry, I realized that perhaps the Alex de Brie example was not the most appropriate. Please, I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152296/how-to-model-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-in-dynamodb) stack overflow question. It is the best stuff I could found. I think it will provide you a clear idea of the different strategies you can follow to store data in DynamoDB. We can review it later in the chat if you consider it appropriate.

Comment: I am online all day :) But for the next 9h I will be sleeping So any other time in the day but this time

Comment: It's okay Jaime. In fact, it is also late here in Madrid. I'm also usually online all day. Please, when you consider it appropriate and you see that I am connected, just tell me and I try to meet you in the chat. Maybe tomorrow morning ... When you prefer. Have a good night.

Comment: The error that arised when you removed the sort keys from the keys on ```Division``` is very likely motivated because doing so we created indexes with only the partition key, ```seasonID``` or ```leagueID```, depending on the case, but probably GraphQL are querying the ```Division``` table with both fields, ```seasonID``` and ```leagueID``` because both ```Season``` and ```League``` are required. Sorry, I am afraid I gave you a wrong advice.

Comment: Oh this is interesting. So yes, if the query includes the model, then it will try to query on the key. I find that odd though, if it returns null I am more than ok with this, I think possibly it should not error from this

Comment: Hi Jaime. Could you try something else? Do you need any help?

Comment: I am actually just trying now :) So meet you in the chat :)

Comment: getting an issue when trying to put another key directive in my table, can you please advise ? 

type PropertyInfoByBedroomType @model(timestamps: null)
 @key(fields: ["skylineId", "bedroomType"])
 @key(name: "byUnitMix", fields: ["skylineId"]) {
  skylineId: ID!
  bedroomType: Int!
  avgSqFt: Float
  askingRentPerUnit: Float
  askingRentPerSqFt: Float
  propertyInfo: PropertyInfo @connection(fields: ["skylineId"])
}

Comment: @IdoBleicher I think your problem is related with `@key(name: "byUnitMix", fields: ["skylineId"])`. This key is unnecessary, you already have a key, your primary index, which already defines the field `skylineId`as your _hash_ key, it looks unnecessary for me. Please, see: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/key#definition

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting two different types of query patterns on the division (one from the League using the league ID and one from the Season using the season ID), you should create two indexes. Try something like this:

```
type League @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  logo: String
  seasons: [Season] @connection(keyName: "bySeason", fields: ["id"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivision", fields: ["id"])
}

type Season @model @key(name: "bySeason", fields: ["leagueID"]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  yearStart: AWSDate
  yearEnd: AWSDate
  leagueID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivisionFromSeason", fields: ["id"])
}

type Division @model
  @key(name: "byDivisionFromSeason", fields: ["seasonID", "leagueID", "name"])
  @key(name: "byDivision", fields: ["leagueID", "seasonID", "name"]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  leagueID: ID!
  seasonID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  season: Season! @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
  ageInput: String!
  level: Int!
}
```

Comment: Ahh pants, you can have more than one key!!! Right I will test this out, thank you

Comment: I have made sure I did the changes in the correct way, I believe I need to read more about `keys` truth be told. But otherwise here is the error

Comment: `  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Query condition missed key schema element",
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:ValidationException",
      "data": null,
      "errorInfo": null,
      "path": [
        "listLeagues",
        "items",
        1,
        "division"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 10,
          "column": 9,
          "sourceName": "GraphQL request"
        }
      ]
    }`

Comment: Hmm, unsure what that error is, I did test this out and it seemed to be working. I wonder if the data in your DB adheres to the updated access pattern.

Comment: Thanks Nader. I have completely removed all data and now started from scratch. I am not sure if this will help, but here is my mocked data. If you are as keen as I am to resolve the issue :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnyLCGj27BEbAKYtgGFr_tGd3-B8XRwL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can confirm that removing `seasons` from the league and the extra key on `Division` type does remove the error. Interestingly though, `League.divisions` returns an empty array. I am wondering if, somehow, this is failing because my divisions isn't correctly writing `leagueID`. I will validate this just now./

Comment: Sadly this wasn't the case. `Division.leagueID` is populated and valid: `    "listDivisions": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "0197eeed-8edf-48c9-84be-70d0f8a02bb6",
          "name": "Senior Two North",
          "faId": "965008463",
          "divisionSeasonFaId": null,
          "leagueID": "9c24b021-4d16-4dbb-99b4-f8b162a3384d",
          "seasonID": "e32c270d-1d6c-4aca-9fc4-94af9a1a9f95",
          "ageInput": "Open",
          "level": 4,
          "createdAt": "2020-10-13T21:31:45.994Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-10-13T21:31:45.994Z"
        },`

Comment: I believe it also worth mentioning that `Season.division` is also a empty array. I wonder if that has any impact?

Comment: As far as I can understand it. The key.fields need to be ID's and unquie?

Comment: I have to stay, I am still very much struggling with this. I just felt for the effort you put in, you deserved the poitns!